# How do I convert an object to an array?

Tags: aura, sobject, javascript-controller, helper

I have a `searchContact` method in the helper. I get from the component a list of contacts of type `object` and try to convert it to an `array`. I want to be able, after conversion, to refer to each element of the array by index and get the value of the "Name" field. But I don't understand why the conversion function `.fromEntries ()` is not working? And I am getting the value of the `contacts` variable as an `[object Object]`.

```
searchContact : function(component, searchKeyword, helper){
    let contacts = Object.fromEntries(component.get('v.contacts'));
    ...
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.fromEntries` converts a key-value pair list (e.g. a Map) to an Object. It appears that you want the opposite; to create an array from an Object, you want `Object.entries`, as in:

```
let contacts = Object.entries(component.get("v.contacts"));
```

Just knowing you have an Object, though, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do. Check `console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.contacts")));` to see what your data looks like.

Comment: My data looks like this: `[ {"Name":"Jack Johns","Email":"test@email.com","Contact_Level__c":"Primary","AccountId":"sdfsd54654sdf899465d4f",
"OwnerId":"kjhk565465sd6f45sd65f4SAD","CreatedById":"kjhk565465sd6f45sd65f4SAD","CreatedDate":"2021-02-07T20:49:46.000Z",
"Id":"sdfsdseLKFekefffEJK","Account":{"Name":"Oil & Gas","Id":"eKJNKJenkjfnKJEF5e4fee"},
"Owner":{"Name":"Jack Smile","Id":"8798dfsdf798798FDS"},"CreatedBy":{"Name":"Jack Smile",
"Id":"8798dfsdf798798FDS"},"AccountName":"Oil & Gas","OwnerName":"Jack Smile",
"CreatedByName":"Jack Smile"}, {"Name":...} ]`

Comment: Converting them through `Object.entries(component.get("v.contacts"))`, i get this (console.log(contacts)): `0,[object Object],1,[object Object],2,[object Object],3,[object Object],4,[object Object],5,[object Object], ... `

Comment: @uniqueuser So it is an array. But what exactly are you trying to do? It looks like the data is already in the format you desire. This may be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: If I convert an object to an array using the method you suggested, then the array will consist of objects of type `object`, and I still won't get the value of the "Name" field of each element. And if we transform, for example, in this way each object in the loop: `Object.entries (component.get ('v.contacts') [0])`, then I get `Name,Jack Johns,Email,test@email.com,Contact_Level__c,Primary,AccountId,sdfsd54654sdf899465d4f, ... this will already be a string with the field name and its value in the string. Again, it is not possible to get the value of the "Name" field.

Comment: @uniqueuser Yes, but what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the values ​​of all the `Name` fields of all the elements that the object contains `(component.get('v.contacts'))`.

Comment: @uniqueuser That'd be something like `component.get('v.contacts').map(record => record.Name);` This would give you an Array full of the names.

Comment: Cool! This is what I need. Thank!